# Getting Java Error - java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo(java.lang.String,int) accessible

Tags: java, coldfusion, commandbox

I have a website running fine on my mac running commandbox v5.0.1+00137 (cfengine: adobe@2023.0.05+330608). I'm setting up a new MBP (M3) which installed commandbox v6.0.0+00787 (cfengine: adobe@2023.0.06+330617). After starting up my dev server and launching the site, I'm getting the following error from a third party component I use called [timezone.cfc](https://github.com/GregoryAlexander77/TimeZone-CFC).

> java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make public sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo(java.lang.String,int) accessible: module java.base does not "exports sun.util.calendar" to unnamed module @591fd34d

The specific parts of the code it chokes on within `timezone.cfc` (line 87) follows...

```html
82: <!--- the time zone object itself --->
83: <cfset variables.tzObj = createObject("java","java.util.TimeZone")>
84: <!--- list of all available timezone ids --->
85: <cfset variables.tzList = listsort(arrayToList(variables.tzObj.getAvailableIDs()), "textnocase")>
86: <!--- default timezone on the server --->
87: <cfset variables.mytz = variables.tzObj.getDefault().ID>
```

Whether I dump `variables.tzObj.getDefault()` -OR- `variables.tzObj.getDefault().ID`, I get...

> [undefined struct element]

When I dump `variables.tzObj`, I get...

[image]

Based on the initial error, this feels like more of a Java issue than a commandbox issue, but I'm not sure. it seems that the `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo(java.lang.String, int) should be public, but is not. Assuming that's the problem, how do I make that public?

Any and all thoughts welcome. I've tried various methods on the object, some work...some do not. The ones that do not (such as `getID()`) seem to throw this error...

> Object instantiation exception.
> An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class must not be an interface or an abstract class. If the class has a constructor that accepts an argument, you must call the constructor explicitly using the init(args) method. Error : ''

Comment: You're actually using date classes that were superseded long ago. You should be calling `java.time.ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` (a static method). So you have the possibility of doing a *double* fix by implementing the above

Comment: Thanks @g00se, it's not my component. It's a 3rd party package I'm using. Not surprising that it may be outdated as it was written a long time ago. But still, I'm not sure how to use your suggestion. The problem occurs when using `java.util.TimeZone` which presumably expects `sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo` to be public. Not even sure where `java.time.ZoneId` would fit into this. Excuse my ignorance. Java is not my strength.

Comment: According to a rapid scan of their README, that relies on a date library called ICU4J...

Answer (score 2):

I only used the `castToUTC` and `castFromUTC` methods of the timezone.cfc library, so rather than continue to troubleshoot why it wasn't working...I wrote my own component limited to the functionality I needed. Here's that component for anyone else who may come across this issue.

```java
component displayname="Timezone Service" hint="Provides methods to convert from/to UTC timezone" {

    public any function init() {
        this.format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        this.LocalDateTime = createObject("java", "java.time.LocalDateTime");
        this.ZoneId = createObject("java", "java.time.ZoneId");
        this.ZonedDateTime = createObject("java", "java.time.ZonedDateTime");
        this.DateTimeFormatter = createObject("java", "java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter");

        return this;
    }
    
    /**
     * Converts given local date-time to UTC.
     * @param localDateTime
     * @param localTimezone Timezone of the local date-time.
     * @return ColdFusion DateTime Object in UTC Timezone
     */
    public date function toUTC(date localDateTime, string localTimezone) {
        var localZone = this.ZoneId.of(localTimezone); // e.g. "US/Pacific"
        var utcZone = this.ZoneId.of("UTC");
    
        // Parse localDateTime to a ZonedDateTime in the local timezone
        var zonedDateTime = this.ZonedDateTime.of(
            this.LocalDateTime.parse(
                DateTimeFormat(arguments.localDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:nn:ss")
            ), 
            localZone
        );
        
        // Convert to UTC
        var utcDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(utcZone);
        
        return utcDateTime.format(
            this.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(this.format)
        );
    }
    
    /**
     * Converts given UTC date-time to local timezone.
     * @param utcDateTime 
     * @param localTimezone target timezone
     * @return ColdFusion DateTime Object in Local Timezone
     */
    public date function fromUTC(date utcDateTime, string localTimezone) {
        var localZone = this.ZoneId.of(localTimezone); // e.g. "US/Pacific"
        var utcZone = this.ZoneId.of("UTC");        
        
        // Parse utcDateTime to a ZonedDateTime in UTC
        var zonedDateTime = this.ZonedDateTime.of(
            this.LocalDateTime.parse(
                DateTimeFormat(arguments.utcDateTime, "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:nn:ss")
            ), 
            utcZone
        );
        
        // Convert to local timezone
        var localDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(localZone);

        return localDateTime.format(
            this.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(this.format)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: *I wrote my own component limited to the functionality* MUCH better! Now you're not tied to a dead api (and I assume) an obsolete library

Comment: @g00se, you're 100% right! Let me know if you notice any room for improvement. As I said, Java is not my strength so I'm sure there's probably plenty of opportunity to improve.

Comment: You've got to be careful about demarcations of object responsibility/functionality. Note that `LocalDateTime` has *no* timezone information at all. All classes 'speak ISO' natively, so don't have to be given an ISO format before they can parse a datetime string. If you're interested in recording an absolute instant in time, you should be using... `Instant`, or `ZonedDateTime`. So in a real way, it doesn't really make sense to adjust `LocalDate`/`LocalDateTime` between timezones, when you should be using `OffsetDateTime` or `Instant` or `ZoneDateTime` in the first place. Date stuff's complex

Comment: So if you can be *really* precise about what you want to do then people here (some of whom are real experts in `java.time`) can take a look. Keep it short, but be *really* precise about your objectives

Comment: My use case is simple. I have a form which allows a user to select a date/time and timezone. I store that in the database as UTC along with the selected timezone. This way I can convert back/forth between user selected and UTC.

Comment: *...which allows a user to select a date/time ...* A little more info could be useful. They are selecting a date (in their chosen timezone) when they want something to happen - or what?

Comment: Exactly, they're scheduling an appointment in their timezone

Comment: So you'll definitely want a `userTimeToServiceTime` function, where you convert the user's datetime in their zone to the instant that's important to you, at the server's zone

Comment: That's basically what I've written here

Comment: Yes indeed. And of course, constrain them to only choosing from Java's available timezones